# Can I get a symbol for a member from an argument name?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am validating child objects of a parent like this:

```
validate :overdue_tasks_valid
validate :created_overdue_tasks_valid
```

I then have methods like this:

```
private
def overdue_tasks_valid
  validate_notification(overdue_tasks, :overdue_tasks)
end

def created_overdue_tasks_valid
  validate_notification(created_overdue_tasks, :created_overdue_tasks)
end

def validate_notification(notification, key)
  return if notification.valid?

  notification.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
    errors.add key, message
  end
end
```

What I want to know, is, can I pass only one argument to validate_notfication and somehow determine the symbol in the method?

So validate notification would be called like this:

```
validate_notification(overdue_tasks)
```

And the method would look like this:

```
def validate_notification(notification)
  return if notification.valid?

  notification.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
    errors.add [SOMEHOW GET THE SYMBOL], message
  end
end
```

Answer (score 0):

No, but you can send the symbol instead:

```
def overdue_tasks_valid
  validate_notification :overdue_tasks
end

def created_overdue_tasks_valid
  validate_notification :created_overdue_tasks
end

def validate_notification(method)
  notification = send method
  return if notification.valid?

  notification.errors.full_messages.each do |message|
    errors.add method, message
  end
end
```

The secret sauce is, of course, [`Object#send`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-1.9.3/Object.html#method-i-send).